# "setProps()" not triggering "useEffect" in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

When I am updating props of functional component in test case, it's not triggering useEffect. However it's updating props in myComp.

**Component Example:**

```
const myComp = ({userId, myAction}) => {
 useEffect(() => {
  myAction(userId);
 }, [userId]);

  return <div>Test</div>
}
```

**Test case Example:**

```
.....
describe('Testing MyComp', () => {
  it('should call myAction with userID', () => {
    const userId = 'testId';
    wrapper.setProps({userId});
    expect(myAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userId);
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`useEffect()` and `useLayoutEffect()` don't get called in the React shallow renderer. See [useEffect not called when the component is shallow renderered](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2086)
 and [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15275).

You should use the `mount` function.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export const MyComp = ({ userId, myAction }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    myAction(userId);
  }, [userId]);

  return <div>Test</div>;
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { MyComp } from './';

describe('67312763', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const props = {
      userId: '1',
      myAction: jest.fn(),
    };
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComp {...props} />);
    expect(props.myAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('1');
    const userId = '2';
    wrapper.setProps({ userId });
    expect(props.myAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('2');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67312763/index.test.tsx (7.221 s)
  67312763
    ✓ should pass (31 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.731 s
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am already using 'mount' function but it seems 'setProps' is not working for me. It's not updating old property. Any guess? I am using enzyme 3.10.0.

Comment: @Paveloosha Added package versions information

Comment: I am also already using `mount` and using `setProps` still does not trigger `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

@slideshowp2 's answer above is correct, BUT if you're like me and found that `setProps` is **STILL not working even when you are using mount**, this might be useful info for you.

React might batch state updates from multiple `setState()` calls into a single update ([check this out](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)), which *might* be async. So then the expect get's triggered, but the setState hasn't run yet (because it's in the JS event loop waiting to be run), and your test fails.

How do you avoid this you may ask? Wrap your expect in a `setTimeout`, so it ends up in the same async place, and will run *after* the `setState`!

Something like this:

```
describe('Testing MyComp', () => {
  it('should call myAction with userID', () => {
    const userId = 'testId';
    wrapper.setProps({userId});
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(myAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userId);
    }, 0)
  });  
});
```

Also, note that I don't *like* this, but it does work.

Comment: JFC thank you... mount + setTimeout for useEffect :rolleyes:

Comment: I've realised since originally posting this, that the answer I had may be wrong. Be sure to check that something like `expect(true).toBe(false)` doesn't also pass :grimacing:

Let me know, we might want to remove this answer. @TheFrack

Comment: i tried this and what @lauchness said happend, `expect(true).toBeFalse()` passed -- so this def not the solution. 

I will add what will work as a post in itself so others can find this helpful

Answer (score 0):

To trigger any hooks, you need to use this package - https://github.com/mikeborozdin/jest-react-hooks-shallow

then in your test

```js
import {act} from 'react-dom/test-utils'

describe('Testing MyComp', () => {
  it('should call myAction with userID', () => {
    const userId = 'testId';

    // if you follow the jest setup in the 
    // jest-react-hooks-shallow you get withHooks
    // enabled in all your tests
    withHooks(()=> {
        act(()=>
            wrapper.setProps({userId})
        );
    });
    wrapper.update();

    expect(myAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userId);
  });  
});
```